# Getting the next rows from my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, windows

I've wrote this code to read from database:

```
SqlDataReader DR1 = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (DR1.Read))
{
Textbox1.text =DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
TextBox2.text = DR1.GetValue(1).ToString();
}
```

This displays the *first* row from the table. How can I continue to iterate through the table and store/display all values?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have [suggested an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10163684) to your question which I hope clears it up a little further (you're question was missing a question). I also added the C# tag which will help make the question visible, and removed the IDE tag (Visual Studio) as it doesn't relate to your question.

Comment: Going by the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) you need to surround your if statement in a loop (possibly modify it so that it's not just constantly writing to `Textbox1` and `TextBox2`) and call `DR1.NextResult()` once you're done using the current result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code works very well

thanks a lot (:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source");
            DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select where BayNumber='" + comboBox1.Text.Trim() + "';", con);
            da.Fill(dsa);


            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k <= 8; k++)
                {


                    textBox1.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[i++]["PatientId"].ToString();
                    label2.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[k++]["Status"].ToString();
                    textBox2.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[i++]["PatientId"].ToString();
                    label4.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[k++]["Status"].ToString();
                    textBox3.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[i++]["PatientId"].ToString();
                    label6.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[k++]["Status"].ToString();
                    textBox4.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[i++]["PatientId"].ToString();
                    label8.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[k++]["Status"].ToString();
                    textBox5.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[i++]["PatientId"].ToString();
                    label10.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[k++]["Status"].ToString();
                    textBox6.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[i++]["PatientId"].ToString();
                    label12.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[k++]["Status"].ToString();
                    textBox7.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[i++]["PatientId"].ToString();
                    label14.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[k++]["Status"].ToString();
                    textBox8.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[i++]["PatientId"].ToString();
                    label16.Text = dsa.Tables[0].Rows[k++]["Status"].ToString();
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a while loop for the SqlDataReader. You may want to use a DataTable or a List collection to store the rows of data.

```
    SqlDataReader DR1 = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(DR1.Read())  // Will read all records
    {
      // This is only useful for a single interation
      Textbox1.text =DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
      TextBox2.text = DR1.GetValue(1).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a while loop to read table

```
    SqlDataReader DR1 = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(DR1.Read())  // While : read all records
        {
          // Your code here
        }
```